# Как создать "базу данных"?

Tags: java, база-данных

Новичок, только начал изучать Java. Объясните, пожалуйста, как создают базы данных в Java. Как изучать, с чего начать, что читать, каким ресурсом пользоваться...)

Comment: Никак. К базе данных можно подключиться. Но это отдельная программа. К какой именно надо?

Comment: Под «базой данных» может подразумеваться что угодно, процесс создания также сильно отличается в зависимости от целей. Почитайте вики для введения в предмет: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создание БД не зависит от языка программирования: будь то Java, PHP или что либо еще. Базы данных создаются в специальных программах под названием СУБД (Система Управления Базой Данных) на данный момент самыми популярными являются MySQL, PostgeSQL, SQLITE и т.д. Для начала вам нужно разобраться с ключевыми понятиями что такое БД, как она работает и в этом духе, далее следует приступить к изучению языку SQL (это специальных язык баз данных, в котором вы можете манипулировать данными и всей и вашей БД) и только после этого следует приступать к взаимодействию с БД через языки прикладного программирования, к примеру тот же Java.
  Собственно по поводу что учить где и как Для новичка я посоветую начать с изучения MySQL. И вот моя подборка обучающих материалов на эту тему:

1. Неплохая книга по языку SQL: http://pv.bstu.ru/database/books/understanding%20sql.pdf
2. А в качестве практики посоветую вот здесь проверять свои знания по языку SQl: http://www.sql-ex.ru/

Надеюсь, что мой ответ был вам хоть чем-то полезен. Удачи в изучении БД, и помните практически никакой проект не обходится без взаимодействия с БД.

Comment: Я бы добавил, что: а) "самыми популярными" могут быть в зависимости от критериев и Oracle, и MS SQL Server, и IBM DB2 и прочие. б). в связке "Java - СУБД" также нужно разобраться с JDBC - мимо него не пройдешь.